# Looking backward and forward in a circular loop in python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I would like to generate a list of single digits based on user input. In a circular iterative way, the list should contain the user input, the two digits before that, and the two digits after that. The order of the digits isn't important.

user_input = "1"
output = [9, 0, 1, 2, 3]

user_input = "9"
output = [7, 8, 9, 0, 1]

Using itertools.cycle I was able to get the next two digits, but I couldn't find an answer that can help me get the previous two digits. Is there a simple way to get those previous two digits?

```
from itertools import cycle
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

user_input = "139"

for i in user_input:    
    s = int(i)
    lst = [s]
    itr = cycle(numbers)
    if s in itr:
        #how can I get the two digits before s?
        lst.append(next(itr))   #getting the next digit
        lst.append(next(itr))

    print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use a list comprehension and `% 10`:

```
>>> for s in range(10):
        print([i % 10 for i in range(s-2, s+3)])

[8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
[9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement like this.

```
def backward_list(n):
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        x = numbers.index(n) 
    else:
        x = (numbers.index(n)-10)
    return [numbers[x-2],numbers[x-1],numbers[x],numbers[x+1],numbers[x+2]]
```

**Execution**

```
In [1]: for i in range(10):
.....:     print backward_list(i)
.....:     
[8, 9, 0, 1, 2]
[9, 0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 0]
[7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This will result in "list index out of range" when the number is 8 or 9!

Comment: @Hesham Thank you for poointing out. Just updated my answer. Really sorry for late update i was busy.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your statements in the iff to this:

```
if s in itr and len(str) == 2:
    lst.append(next(itr))   #getting the next digit
    lst = [s - 1] + lst # prepend the first value
    lst.append(next(itr))
    lst = [s - 2] + lst # prepend the second value
```

Or you can also do

```
if s in itr and len(str) == 2:
    lst.append(next(itr))   #getting the next digit
    lst.insert(0, s-1) # prepend the first value
    lst.append(next(itr))
    lst.insert(0, s-2) # prepend the second value
```

Comment: This does not work when the user_input is 1 or less because it does not circle around.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But you can do a check to make sure that string should be at least 2 to cycle. Answer has been updated. I did that since you did not mention the other condition, but the condition has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a range from the input and use that range to slice a numpy array

edit: my bad for writing code and not testing it... thanks @Stefan Pochmann for pointing that out...

```
import numpy as np

def cycle(x):  #x is user input
    indices = np.array(range(x-2, x+3))%10
    numbers = np.array(range(10))
    return numbers[indices]
```

Comment: Crashes for `cycle(9)`.